# Adding records to junction table JPA

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have problem with adding records to my junction table with JPA+Hibernate

[image: The schema is]

when I try to add simple record with POST request it's throws me an error:

> "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

And in my console:

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*

I had defined Join columns `@JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false)` because it was demanding by Hibernate, otherwise it throws me an error that I should do that...

Here is my junction entity code:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "hospital_doctor")
@IdClass(Hosdoc.class)
public class HospitalDoctor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int hospitalId;

    @Id
    private int doctorId;


    // fields of hospitalDoctor table

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date contractStartDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date contractEndDate;
    private String position;
    private String supervisor;
    private boolean partTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="HospitalId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Hospital hospital;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DoctorId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Doctor doctor;

// GETTERS AND SETTERS....
```

I wrote simple adding function in hospital class but I don't know how to use it to add record to junction table by POST request.

```
public void addDoctor(Doctor doctor, boolean partTime, Date contractEndDate, Date contractStartDate,
            String position, String supervisor) {
        HospitalDoctor association = new HospitalDoctor();
        association.setDoctor(doctor);
        association.setHospital(this);
        association.setDoctorId(doctor.getId());
        association.setHospitalId(this.getId());
        association.setContractStartDate(contractStartDate);
        association.setContractEndDate(contractEndDate);
        association.setPosition(position);
        association.setSupervisor(supervisor);
        association.setPartTime(partTime);

        doctors.add(association);
    }
```

Service:

```
    public void addHospitalDoctor(HospitalDoctor hospitalDoctor) {
    hospitalDoctorDao.save(hospitalDoctor);
}
```

Controller:

```
        @PostMapping(value = "/api/hospitaldoctors")
    public void addHospitalDoctor(HospitalDoctor hospitalDoctor) {
        hospitalDoctorService.addHospitalDoctor(hospitalDoctor);
    }
```

Comment: Does the other tables have a `mappedBy` annotation option?

Comment: Yes, Problem is I don't know how to set Doctor and Hospital for HospitalDoctor in POST method. I will add my service and controller, and if you would like look at this I will be glad :)

Comment: you should just store the fk to get it to map? or send the object (embedded json)

Comment: the pair of FK is a primary Key in HospitalDoctor.Primary key (HospitalId, DoctorId)